# A question about whether a function is $0$ a.e. on its entire domain.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, almost-everywhere, measurable-sets

Let $u = u(t,x)$, where $(t,x) \in [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^d$ and for a fixed $1 \le p < \infty$,  $ u(t,\cdot) \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for
all $t \in [0,T]$.

My question is,

if $\Vert u(t,\cdot)\Vert_{L^p} = 0 $ a.e. $ t\in [0,T]$, then $u \equiv 0$ on $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^d$ a.e.? Please share your wisdom. Thanks!

Comment: $u(t,\cdot)$, in general, can be different from $0$ in a subset of $[0,T]$ that has zero measure, for example the set of rational point in $[0,T]$ is a non-empty set with measure zero. For example, it can be $u(t,\cdot)=0$, for $t$ irrational, and $u(t,\cdot)$ a fixed non zero function $\in L^p(\mathbb R^d)$, for $t$ rational.

Comment: @Alessandro  Sorry I think my question was a little confusing. I changed $ u(t,\cdot) = 0 $ to $\Vert u(t, \cdot)\Vert_{L^p} = 0 $ and also from $u \equiv 0$ on $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^d$ a.e. Would you look at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $(t,x)\to u(t,x)$ is measurable (this can be slightly relaxed) then yes.

This is exactly what [Fubini-Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) is for.

Let $A= \{(t,x): u(t,x)=0\}$. Then

$$(\lambda\times \lambda) (A) = \iint {\bf 1}_A (t,x) d \lambda \times \lambda = \int_{[0,T]} \left(\int_{{\mathbb R}^d} {\bf 1}_A (t,x) d\lambda (x)\right) d \lambda (t)=0.$$

The first equality is by definition, the second by Fubini-Tonelli (which also claims that the inner integral is a measurable function).  By assumption the inner integral is zero a.e., and therefore the entire integral is zero, giving the last equality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! :)